# Issue calling a custom view method from runnable

Tags: java, android, handler

I am using a handler to call runnable after a delay of 5 seconds. this then calls a method in a custom view. the problem im having is that the method is being called but the delay is far greater than 5 seconds.

code is as follows.

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
public void run()
{
    buttonArray.get(1).activate();
}
}, 5000);
```

and the code in the custom view that is being called

```
public void activate()
{
    active = true;
    this.animate().alpha(0.4f).setDuration(150);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you determining how long it is taking? The reason I ask, is if you're doing it from the debugger, the debugger can really slow things down. Also, when it does that, it post to the UI thread, so depending on what the UI thread is doing it might take a while.

Comment: the delay is infact around 10 seconds.

Comment: By any chance do you (or some other library you are using) use other handlers as well ? My wild guess would be that something is pumping way to many messages to the main handler (Looper) thus your message can't be processed on time

Comment: if, instead of calling the methodactivate() which uses animation, i just say buttonArray.get(1).setAlpha(1); it works as expected.

Comment: to my knowledge I am not using any other Handlers